# PHP foreach add code for every 4 results found

Tags: php, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On every third iteration in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093017/on-every-third-iteration-in-php)

Using PHP foreach to get a series of results,how would I add the following echo `'<div class="clear"><div>'` every 4 results

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using modulos can do the trick :

```
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $result) {
    if($i % 4 === 0) {
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```